# save current page of gridview when page dropdownlist selected index change

Tags: asp.net

I am using a multi page gridview to display bunch of data. Here is the code of the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="unverifiedlist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true"  OnRowDataBound="unverifiedlist_RowDataBound" style="font-size:12px" >
                        <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname" ReadOnly="true"/></Columns>
                        <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Firstname" DataField="Givenname" ReadOnly="true"/></Columns>
                       ......
                        <Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="options" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="options_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Verified</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Rejected</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Reason">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="reason" runat="server" OnTextChanged ="reason_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerSettings Visible="false"/>            
            </asp:GridView>


<asp:DropDownList ID="PageSelect" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageSelect_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

there is a column called "option" which contains a dropdownlist, and it will postback everytime when the selected index was changed to save the edited row. I am trying to avoid this frequent postback. So i think if I can save the whole page before user turn to the next page. 
The problem is the "PageSelect" dropdownlist's postback will trigger the page reload first, then onselectedindexchanged event, at this point, the gridview already turned to the next page. So can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the gridview itself's paging navigation control instead of my dropdownlist at last. Then I am able to use the pageindexchanging event to save the current page into a session before it goes to the next page

Answer (score 0):

You can set EnableSortingAndPagingCallBacks property of the grid view to true , but that wont work if you are using template fields in your gridview, for maintaining the state of the page, you will have to keep the value of current page in session and on page load you can check the session..